# Adding an image to a twitter share

Tags: javascript, html, twitter

I have something like...

```
onClick{() => window.open('https://twitter.com/intent/tweet?text=test&url=https://stackoverflow.com&hashtags=stack')
```

Is it possible to add an image to the tweet if I have a url it?

Comment: unless the image is already hosted on twitter, you cant

Comment: ok, thanks. what about facebook?